# Unable To Use Localhost Port 80 ; Error starting userland proxy: Bind for 0.0.0.0:80: unexpected error (Failure EADDRINUSE)

Tags: apache, docker, networking, port, portforwarding

I am using a Mac Book Pro

I need to use my localhost Port :80 but i keep getting this ERROR message:

> Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external 
>   connectivity on endpoint nostalgic_ride : Error starting userland
>   proxy:
>
> Bind for 0.0.0.0:80: unexpected error (Failure EADDRINUSE).

this issue arose because i tried to use docker to do this:

```
docker run -it -p 80:80 -p 443:443 nginx
```

I did a search to see what is listening on all my ports:

> sudo lsof -nP | grep LISTEN

```
UserEvent   41               root  113u     IPv6 0xa09c168d9d24ed2f         0t0      TCP [fe80:8::aede:48ff:fe00:1122]:49153 (LISTEN)
UserEvent   41               root  114u     IPv6 0xa09c168d9d24e1af         0t0      TCP [fe80:8::aede:48ff:fe00:1122]:49154 (LISTEN)
UserEvent   41               root  115u     IPv6 0xa09c168d9d24dbef         0t0      TCP [fe80:8::aede:48ff:fe00:1122]:49155 (LISTEN)
UserEvent   41               root  116u     IPv6 0xa09c168d9d24f2ef         0t0      TCP [fe80:8::aede:48ff:fe00:1122]:49156 (LISTEN)
php-fpm     48               root    8u     IPv4 0xa09c168d9d7b322f         0t0      TCP 127.0.0.1:9000 (LISTEN)
php-fpm    221               _www    9u     IPv4 0xa09c168d9d7b322f         0t0      TCP 127.0.0.1:9000 (LISTEN)
php-fpm    222               _www    9u     IPv4 0xa09c168d9d7b322f         0t0      TCP 127.0.0.1:9000 (LISTEN)
EEventMan  351               tom    4u     IPv4 0xa09c168da7672eaf         0t0      TCP *:2968 (LISTEN)
java       648               tom   69u     IPv6 0xa09c168d9d24c4ef         0t0      TCP [fe80:1::1]:49185 (LISTEN)
LogiMgrDa  715               tom    4u     IPv4 0xa09c168da914f52f         0t0      TCP *:59866 (LISTEN)
httpd      860               root    4u     IPv6 0xa09c168da64892ef         0t0      TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
httpd      864               _www    4u     IPv6 0xa09c168da64892ef         0t0      TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
httpd      955               _www    4u     IPv6 0xa09c168da64892ef         0t0      TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
```

**Questions:**

- It appears that there are 3 instances of httpd listening on Port 80. If so, does anyone know what these httpd are for and whether it's safe to remove them.
- If so, how do I kill/remove them.

**ANSWER TO SIMILAR QUESTIONS ON THIS ISSUE:**

these answers do not help me beucase they all recommend simply changing the port. however i need port 80 for localhost development

Comment: This may help [How do I stop httpd running under Mac OS X (10.11) El Capitan Server?](https://superuser.com/q/1033406/963933)

Comment: hi @b0gusb thanks for response. do you have any idea why  apple proxy service uses these ports. will i lose anything vital if i shut it down/

Comment: Which version of Mac OS are you running?

Comment: HI @b0gusb . ITS VERSION 10.14.2

Comment: If you have installed Server.app the `httpd` processes, most likely, belong to the [web proxy](https://help.apple.com/serverapp/mac/5.3/#/apdf37747285).